# The proper use of Scanner and his methods

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong... Here is my code:

```
    String str = "Stan: " + System.getProperty("line.separator") + "2 . 3 | 1";
    Scanner src = new Scanner(str).useDelimiter("\\s*[Stan:]+\\s*|\\s*[|]\\s+|\\p{javaWhitespace}+");
    while(src.hasNext()) {
        if(src.next().equals(".")) {
            System.out.println("0");
        } else {
            System.out.println(src.next());
        }
    }

    src.close();
```

And I get this:

```
.
1
```

If I delete else { } I will get 0, what is correct.

What I want? Using the full code above I would like to get in output this, but each number should be type of int:

```
2
0
3
1
```

I'd appreciate your help guys!

**UPDATE:**
I need this code for this kind of input:

```
Some text with spaces:
1 . 3 | 2 . .
-------------
8 2 . | 9 . .
```

Comment: I don't understand the update to the question.

Comment: In this input I have spaces between text, but in previous input I have only one word... And I don't want to create pattern for each word. Is that possible to omit all text - all letters? And read only dots and numbers?

Answer (score 0):

You are potentially calling `next` twice each loop.

Just store it once and use it later more than once, so you don't advance two tokens when you meant to advance only one token.

```
String next = src.next();
if(next.equals(".")) {
    System.out.println("0");
} else {
    System.out.println(next);
}
```